# how to set text size in xcode 7 simulator for ios 9?

Tags: ios, xcode

can not set text size for dynamic type in xcode 7 simulator for ios 9. field named text size need to be in settings in general below about field. but there is not .how to set text size in xcode 7 simulator for ios 9?

Comment: now it is  in General in Accessibility in Larger Text

Comment: This does not appear to to be working any more in the simulator for me (simulator 9.3).  It used to work, but now changing this setting does nothing, in my apps or in the Settings app itself.